# Override validation message on spree credit card create during checkout

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm trying to override the following error message during `checkout/payment` on Spree 1.3

When the user forgets to enter credit card number, month or cvv, this message is displayed:

`Payments source is invalid`

```
module Spree
  class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :month, :year, :numericality => { :only_integer => true }
    validates :number, :presence => true, :unless => :has_payment_profile?, :on => :create
    validates :verification_value, :presence => true, :unless => :has_payment_profile?, :on => :create
```

The validations on create above are sending this error message, that I would like to override, with something a little more useful, like: `Please check the credit card information entered.`

Does anyone know how to override create a custom error message when validation doesn't pass.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
module Spree
  class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :verification_value, :presence => true, :unless => :has_payment_profile?, :on => :create,
  message: "%{value} is reserved." }
end
```

Comment: I ended up overriding it in views instead